# This is multiselection box and required field as well. I mean 'aria-selected' is getting true after i un-select all values from selection box.

Tags: jquery, selectmanylistbox

Case-1 : Select the two customers 'Customer ---> aa,bb' from selection box and save the record.(Saving successfully. )
Case-2 : Un-select two customers 'Customer ---> aa,bb' from selection box and save the record, it won't save because this selection box is required = "true". Showing required validation message and as well as selecting previous un-selected 'aa,bb' customers once again.

I want to show only 'required validation' message only if we un-select all values from selection box, i don't want to auto selection on save button.
Note : This is happening only when required="true", if it isn't required then behaving fine like what i am expecting

Comment: If required is true then why you want to unselect saved values?

Comment: post some code that's **required**

Comment: @ntechi : You are right, but QA team will test those things

Comment: Are you using same code for create and edit?

Comment: @Jai : <h:selectManyListbox id="#{id}"
             value="#{value}"
             required="#{required}" 
             disabled="#{disabled}"
              hideNoSelectionOption="#{hideNoSelectionOption}"
             styleClass="multiselector#{filterClass} #{validate} #{styleClass}"
           style="display:none;">
                   
              <s:selectItems var="item" value="#{selectItemsValue}"
                label="#{selectItemsLabel}"
                noSelectionLabel="#{noSelectionLabel}" disabled="#{selectItemDisabledCondition}" />
           
           
   </h:selectManyListbox>

Comment: @ntechi : I am using same code for create and edit and using widget as http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
function check(required) {

    if (required && $("#Customer :selected").length == 0) {
        alert("selection is required!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But seems to be not solvable my issue, because when we click on 'Save' button once again rendering(selecting) previous un-selected check boxes.(If there is no required="true" then no issue at my side). I think issue at 'jquery-ui-multiselect-widget' here needs to trigger 'refresh' somewhere